# Kivy: draw a hatched rectangle for a progressbar

Tags: kivy, progress-bar, line, rectangles

I want to build a custom progressbar with a hatched line filling up a rectangle.
At the end it shold look something like this (colors can be differnt):
[image] 
The hatched lines should have a 45 degree angle and one should be able to set the thickness of the lines in the hatching.

I`m using python 3.7.3 and kivy 1.10.1

My code so far only gives me the backround rectangle with a borderline.

[image]But on the rectangle that should fill up from left to right the hatching is missing and i have no good idea how to do it.

I tried it with a png file as a texture but the results were poor (file pb_filled.png). The resizing did not work properly.

I would prefer a solution that can be done only in kv. 
Is it possible to use lines to make the hatching? 
I maybe later want to animate the lines moving from right to left.
Please help me to get the hatching on the rectange done.

```
<CustomProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    height: '100'
    size_hint: (1, None)
    canvas:
        BorderImage:
            border: (3, 3, 3, 3)
            pos: self.x, self.y
            size: self.width, 75
            source: 'pb_normal.png'
        Color:
            rgb: 123/255,123/255,54/255,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.x, self.y
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 75
            #source: 'pb_filled.png'
```

Comment: I would probably be inclined to use a texture, but manipulate the tex_coords and wrapping method to have it tile the progressbar instead of stretching. Also, don't worry about doing it "only in kv", there isn't much value in that.

Comment: Consider using [StencilView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html#module-kivy.uix.stencilview). If you put a "completed" progress bar image inside a `StencilView`, you can just adjust the width of the `StencileView` to show as much of the progress as you want.

Comment: Thank you i got it working with a StenciView. I added this code below: `StencilView:
        pos: self.parent.x, self.parent.y
        size: self.parent.width * (self.parent.value / float(self.parent.max)) if self.parent.max else 0, 75
        Image:
            source: 'pb_filled.png'
#            border: [int(min(self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 12))] * 4
            pos: self.parent.x, self.parent.y
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: '75dp'
            width: '2000dp'`